# Is there software for converting a picture of a board into an schematic?

Tags: schematics, board

I need to reverse-engineer several simple single-sided boards. I have very good quality pictures of them so I was thinking that maybe there is software capable of getting the schematic from the pictures (up & down) or at least an approximation.

How can I reverse engineer PCB's easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No s/w that I know of. However, you could overlay a transparency onto a picture of the board and draw the electronic symbol over the picture of the component, then add the wiring links. All you would have to do then is re-arrange the circuit for readability

Comment: Good idea! Thanks. Anyway this could be an opportunity to create such tool.

Comment: What "opportunity"? Is there a general need (i.e., a market) for a tool like this?

Comment: @DaveTweed Possibly. I have wanted to do this on a number of occasions over the years. The question is how much would I pay for it?

Comment: A *reliable* tool like this might be handy. Here is paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050916300783

Answer (score 2):

Visio seems to work well for me (any before graphics software will do), put the picture of the PCB as a background or layer and draw a schematic on top. You can also have multiple layers and put the to and bottom of the PCB to trace on the same file. You can change the visibility of the layers and trace over both. If you could x Ray inner layers those could also be traced

Answer (score 1):

I have just stumbled upon [Image2schematic](https://github.com/s39674/Image2schematic), and it seems to be a good fit for the purpose. It's using OpenCV for image detection and modification and skidl for building out a schematic. In addition, PCB-CD is used to classify PCB components and EasyOCR to read text on chips. I have not yet used this software, but I will give it a try.